# 'Watcher' program for messageboxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to brainstorm how to go about creating a program that will be actively running alongside my application and will watch for messageboxes to be shown in the application and take all the information(text, buttons, parameters) included with that messagebox and house them as an object in a global variable available throughout my application.

Is there anyway to tell programatically in my application that a messagebox is about to appear and to take any information related to it and place it in an object?  Aside from having to scan the code, which isn't what I'm looking for especially since there's many places messageboxes will appear, this would give incorrect information.

Or is there a better way to go about this?  All I'm looking for is information associated with the messagebox that is about to appear(and not show the messagebox then)

Any tips or websites I could reference is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Odd request.  It's your code, find the MessageBox calls and replace them yourself.  Hacking-wise, maybe create your own class called MessageBox with the same shared `Show()` functions.

Comment: I would otherwise just replace all of them myself but the application is huge and has hundreds of messagebox calls so the effort will be huge.  I will try creating a class, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class that takes in the same parameters as the standard messagebox.show and then calls the messagebox.show passing the parameters on. When you are ready, you can then put some code before the standard call that will capture the information.

I always create my own messagebox.show so I can control it. It's nice to have a standard title and there maybe time that you need to do special stuff with it, like log the messages.

BTW, because of scoping, if your class is in the same project, yours will be used instead of the standard, unless you fully qualified it: system.windows.forms.messagebox.show().